# check broken links on a page using nightwatch

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

As the title says, my goal is to check if there are any broken links on a given page. By links, I mean "href" attributes of "a" tags. Ideally, I'd like to target some specific "a" tags (for example those contained in specific section of the page, in nav tag for example...).

Background: I'm trying to build a "complete" testing app for a website. I'm currently working on the functional tests part. 
In that context, I'd like to make sure that all the links in a specific page send you somewhere (no 404).
What I used to do, was simply find the link using a hard coded selector, click on it, check that the landing page has a title...

```
.waitForElementVisible("//div[@class='selectorForlink1']")
.waitForElementVisible("//div[@class='selectorForlink2']")
.click("//div[@class='selectorForButtonToClickOn']")
.waitForElementVisible("//ul[@class='selectorForLink3']/li[2]")
.click("//ul[@class='selectorForButtonToClickOnNo2']/li[2]")
```

Obviously, this is dirty/inefficient. I've found a post on another related subject, that was advising to extract the links of the page, store them (in arrays I guess) open each in an HTTP stream, verify the response content.

For the test of the response, I would use that piece of code (also found on another related thread):

```
const request = require('request');
request(myArrayOfLinkObject, (error, response, body) => {
    browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
});
```

My only problem here, would be on puting all the a tag element in an array (I'm not familiar at all with xpath selectors, or nightwach syntax...). the last thing I unsuccessfully tried is this:

```
browser.elements('xpath', "//a[@class='Something']/@href", function (elements) 
{
    listofelements=elements;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, I found something that worked for me, maybe it'll work for someone else... there it is (with a random css selector):

```
browser.elements('css selector', "nav a", function (linksOfThePage)
      {
        numberOfLinks=linksOfThePage.value.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < numberOfLinks; x++){ 
          browser.elementIdAttribute(linksOfThePage.value[x].ELEMENT, "href", function(links) { 
            console.log(links.value);
            request(links.value, (error, response, body) => {
                browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
              });
          });
        }
      })
```

It's probably not the cleanest way, but should do the job... At least it has for me